# Почему функция возвращает "undefined"?

Tags: javascript

Почему `check` возвращает "undefined", а `check2` - нормальный результат?

```
function check(url) {
return
    typeof url != 'undefined' &&
        url != '' &&
        url != location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname;
}

function check2(url) {
var result =
    typeof url != 'undefined' &&
        url != '' &&
        url != location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname;

    return result;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5c2wb689/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Автоматическая расстановка `;` не всегда срабатывает верно, в данном случае точка с запятой была автоматически поставлена в конце строки после `return`. Не забывайте скобки в таких случаях, если переносите строку - вот [ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA_%D1%81_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8) на документацию

```
return(
  typeof url != 'undefined' &&
    url != '' &&
    url != location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname
);
```

Answer (score 3):

В одну строку надо писать.

Скорее просто перед `return` не должно быть перехода на следующую строку

```js
function check(url) {
  return typeof url != 'undefined' && url != '' && url != location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname;
}

function check2(url) {
  var result =
    typeof url != 'undefined' &&
    url != '' &&
    url != location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname;

  return result;
}

alert(check('https://yandex.ru'));
alert(check2('https://yandex.ru'));
```

Comment: Писать в одну строку не всегда удобно, надо скобки не забывать

Comment: согласен, но привычка вещь упрямая...)))